# SQL get attributes from parent row to child

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table that has both the parent and child data in the same table. I want to get some attributes from the parent row on to the child row (see attached screenshot). The top part is what I have and the result section is what I want. The relationships are just one level deep.

How can I achieve this?

TIA

[image]

Comment: Tag your DBMS - the answer may vary substantially between platforms.

Comment: Your sample data is perhaps too simple. Add id 444, with parent 333 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* your relations are just one-level deep, then you can simply self-join the table:

```
select 
    t.ID,
    coalesce(p.subject, t.subject) Subject,
    t.MeetingTime,
    t.Company,
    t.Parent
from mytable t
left join mytable p on p.id = t.parent
```

---

New query after OP was edited:

```
select 
    t.ID,
    coalesce(p.MeetingTime, t.MeetingTime) MeetingTime,
    coalesce(p.Subject, t.Subject) Subject
    t.Comments,
    t.Company,
    t.Parent
from mytable t
left join mytable p on p.id = t.parent
```

Comment: Thank you. Your way got me a couple steps closer. However, when I run the mentioned query, the meeting date and subject is null for child rows. I want the parents meeting date and subject to come to be reflected on the child rows. But the children should retain their own comments

Comment: @user3108631: I think that you edited your post pretty much at the time when I posted my answer. I updated my answer accordingly. The logic stays the same, just different columns are used.

Comment: Thank you so much. Coalesce is not working for subject field, but I think I can figure out why. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome @user3108631! Glad that it helped out. Keep in mind that this only works one level deep (this is not a recursive query).